# Azure - Connecting .NET web app with azure sql database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a team project and I'm trying to publish the app at Azure, which I successfully did. I was able to get our database to Azure SQL server, but now I'm struggling with connecting the app with this database.

Originaly the app is working with a .mdf file locally, but now, when I'm publishing the app, I want to use the DB at azure server. I changed all the connection strings of `.mdf` file

```
(@"Data Source = (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename =" + Path.GetFullPath(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"..\..\..\PATH"))
```

in the code to the azure database connection string

```
(@"Data Source = Server=tcp:nameofserver.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=sqlmusicdb;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=...;Password=...;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;")
```

but after publishing, the app is not connected to database, as it is writing

> AN ERROR OCCURRED WHILE PROCESSING YOUR REQUEST

Any help, please? Thanx.

Comment: please share the entire error

Comment: that's it, nothing more, just that an error occured.. but on that side it is supposed to show some info and hypertext to pick an user from DB.  now i'm setting logs on azure, to see, what's happening exactly.

Comment: @Maemi what you posted isn't an error. It's whan the end user would see if the web site crashed. Add logging to your application, log all unhandled exceptions and check the generated error messages. Using Application Insights is a quick solution to this

Answer (score 3):

Your connection string is formatted incorrectly.  Remove the

> Data Source =

at the very beginning of your connection string and it should work.